# How to handle multipart/mixed in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, middleware, multipart-mixed-replace

I have been trying to read multipart/mixed data in nodejs.

I have tried using `bodyparser`, `busboy-connect`, and few other modules but nothing seems to parse this data into `req.body`.

So if someone has any idea about how to implement this please leave an answer below.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you try using formidable module?

Comment: yes,but it does not work.

Answer (score -1):

```
app.use(myMiddleware);
 function myMiddleware(req, res, next) {
     req.rawBody = req.body;
     if (req.headers["content-type"] === "multipart/mixed") {
         req.body = req.body;
     }
     next();
}
```